# Dojo - "Tried to register widget with id==centerPane but that id is already registered"

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm having trouble with a content pane in Dojo where it is appearing for a second with the content then disappearing. I am getting the following error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: dijit is not defined index.php:22
    dojo/parser::parse() error 
    Error
    arguments: undefined
    get stack: function () { [native code] }
    message: "Tried to register widget with id==centerPane but that id is already registered"
    set stack: function () { [native code] }
    type: undefined
    __proto__: d
```

I have come accross answer where you can destroy all registered ID's but I am still getting the error when I try them.

```
var ids = ["contentPane"];
dijit.registry.forEach(function(w){ 
   if(dojo.indexOf(ids,id)){
        w.destroyRecursive();
   }
});
```

and

```
var ids = ["contentPane"];

dijit.registry.forEach(function(w){ 
   if(dojo.indexOf(ids,1)){ // 1 will be yourid it will get destroy
        w.destroyRecursive();
   }
});
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, was something simple but I'll stick the answer up in case anyone else does my mistake.
My original code:

```
    <script>
      require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"],
        function (parser) {
        parser.parse();
      });
</script>
```

Fixed code:

```
<script>
  require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when parseOnLoad was set to true. In my understanding it enables the Widget registration. Once I disabled the error gone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {          
        parseOnLoad:false,
```

.....